# Worth of an old 1/4 tanka coin when it was active 1516-1526

Tags: india, money, numismatics

Can someone tell me what was the worth of a quarter tanka  in India when Ibrahim Lodi's was the ruler (1516-1526 CE) or what a quarter tank could buy at that time?

Comment: CCSA image: https://commons.m.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Quarter_Tanka_during_the_period_of_Ibrahim_Lodhi.jpg#mw-jump-to-license

Comment: No inflation calculator for what is now India exists back to 1520, probably because no series exist. The answer will need to Ben in terms of market commodities or rate systems of tax of the day.

Comment: This source from wikis Lodi Dynasty may help: Haider, Najaf (1996). "Precious Metal Flows and Currency Circulation in the Mughal Empire". Journal of the Economic and Social History of the Orient. 39 (3): 298–364. doi:10.1163/1568520962601180. JSTOR 3632649.

Comment: Richards, John F. (August 1965). "The Economic History of the Lodi Period: 1451-1526". Journal of the Economic and Social History of the Orient. 8 (1). JSTOR 3596342. (Subscription required (help)).

Answer (score 1):

According to the primary source of first page of Richards, John F. (August 1965). "The Economic History of the Lodi Period: 1451-1526". Journal of the Economic and Social History of the Orient. 8 (1); 2.5 yards of cloth. This was apparently remarkably good.